# How do I check if the next item in a string is the alphabetical successor of the one before? + Inverse

Tags: python

I'm trying to compress a string in a way that any sequence of letters in strict alphabetical order is swapped with the first letter plus the length of the sequence.

For example, the string "abcdefxylmno", would become: "a6xyl4"

Single letters that aren't in order with the one before or after just stay the way they are.

How do I check that two letters are successors (a,b) and not simply in alphabetical order (a,c)? And how do I keep iterating on the string until I find a letter that doesn't meet this requirement?

I'm also trying to do this in a way that makes it easier to write an inverse function (that given the result string gives me back the original one).

EDIT :

I've managed to get the function working, thanks to your suggestion of using the alphabet string as comparison; now I'm very much stuck on the inverse function: given "a6xyl4" expand it back into "abcdefxylmno".
After quite some time I managed to split the string every time there's a number and I made a function that expands a 2 char string, but it fails to work when I use it on a longer string:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as abc



def subString(start,n):
    L=[]
    ind = abc.index(start)
    newAbc = abc[ind:]
    for i in range(len(newAbc)):
        while i < n:
            L.append(newAbc[i])
            i+=1
        res = ''.join(L)
        return res
    
        
def unpack(S):
    for i in range(len(S)-1):
        if S[i] in abc and S[i+1] not in abc:
            lett = str(S[i])
            num = int(S[i+1])
            return subString(lett,num)
        
def separate(S):
    lst = []
    for i in S:
        lst.append(i)
    for el in lst:
        if el.isnumeric():
            ind = lst.index(el)
            lst.insert(ind+1,"-")
    a = ''.join(lst)
    L = a.split("-")
    if S[-1].isnumeric():
        L.remove(L[-1])
        return L
    else:
        return L

def inverse(S):
    L = separate(S)
    for i in L:
        return unpack(i)
```

Each of these functions work singularly, but inverse(S) doesn't output anything. What's the mistake?

Comment: What have you tried? Post your code [mre].

Comment: Why doesn't`xy` become `x2`?

Comment: @fsimonjetz it should, sorry - i wrote it with the italian alphabet in mind, where we don't have x and y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This builds on the idea that acceptable subsequences will be substrings of the ABC:

```py
from string import ascii_lowercase as abc # 'abcdefg...'

text = 'abcdefxylmno'

stack = []
cache = ''

# collect subsequences
for char in text:
    if cache + char in abc:
        cache += char
    else:
        stack.append(cache)
        cache = char

# if present, append the last sequence     
if cache:
    stack.append(cache)

# stack is now ['abcdef', 'xy', 'lmno']
        
# Build the final string 'a6x2l4'        
result = ''.join(f'{s[0]}{len(s)}' if len(s) > 1 else s for s in stack)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ord()` function which returns an integer representing the Unicode character. Sequential letters in alphabetical order differ by 1. Thus said you can implement a simple funtion:

```
def is_successor(a,b):
    # check for marginal cases if we dont ensure 
    # input restriction somewhere else
    if ord(a) not in range(ord('a'), ord('z')) and ord(a) not in range(ord('A'),ord('Z')):
        return False
    if ord(b) not in range(ord('a'), ord('z')) and ord(b) not in range(ord('A'),ord('Z')):
        return False
    # returns true if they are sequential
    return ((ord(b) - ord(a)) == 1)
```

You can use `chr(int)` method for your reversing stage as it returns a string representing a character whose Unicode code point is an integer given as argument.